# Data structure for category

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures, tree, c5

I am looking for a data structure to add, remove, get, and find on categories.

**For example:**

### Books

- Drama
- Science fiction
- Other

### Sports

- Cycling
- Golf
- Team Sports

  - Soccer
  - Football

etc.

I think about using tree from the [C5 collection library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C5_Generic_Collection_Library_for_C_Sharp_and_CLI) for example, but it looks like it has only red-black trees.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

You can just create a Category class that exposes a list of other Category instances.

```
public class Category
{
    public Category()
    {
        this.ChildCategories = new List<Category>();
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IList<Category> ChildCategories { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: this is start feeling like a tree to me...
how do you put the next item? for example add soccer node as a child of team-sports node which is a child of Sports child...
[Why implement this... when you can use a tree...]

Comment: +1 I like your answer, but use a Dictionary instead of a List.

Comment: @rabashani: Create a new Category instance and give it the Name "Soccer", then add it to the ChildCategories of another Category instance with the Name "Team Sports", etc.

Answer (score 3):

A tree would be a good approach, but I get the feeling you are thinking there is going to be a one-size-fits-all data structure that you could use and that is not really how I envision it.  I concur with Mark's solution, but recommend a Dictionary instead of a List.  That way you can lookup a Category and get its subcategories quickly.